# IE only JQuery script is not firing off

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have the following script:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("ie");
    $('#usa').mapster({
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        fadeInterval: 50
    });
    });
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usa').mapster({
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        fadeInterval: 50
    });
    });
    </script>
```

If the browser is anything other than IE the second script should fire off, but if it's IE the first script should fire off. Although I see the alert statement fire but the rest of the script is being used from the second javascript.

The only issue is because,

> fillOpacity: 0.1

I want it to be 0.1 in IE but 0.9 in other browsers.

Comment: You're attempting to use conditional CSS code with JavaScript.

Comment: What version of IE is it not working on?

Comment: IE will run **both** scripts, not just the first one. Is that what you want?

Comment: In IE, both scripts are being run. So anything you did in the first script is being overwritten by the second script.

Comment: > I don't see any difference in your script apart from the alert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are still firing the base code after the IE code. If all you wish to change is the opacity then do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
opacity = 0.9;
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
opacity =  0.1;
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usa').mapster({
        fillOpacity: opacity,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        fadeInterval: 50
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You could also use JScript conditional comment

Comment: Thank you Richard for the simple answer.